# Alarm Manager Accuracy

Tags: android

How to use alarm manager at accurate time interval?

I used alarm manager but it response inaccurate.
Can anyone help me?
I used this code

```
PendingIntent sender;
AlarmManager am;
long firstTime;
Intent itnt = new Intent();
itnt.setAction("abts.medismo.medismo.ALARMRECEIVER");
sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,itnt, 0);
am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.cancel(sender);
firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
am.setInExactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,firstTime, Integer.parseInt(sep[3]),  sender);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`, because if the phone is asleep it wont fire until it wakes up again.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here.

The first, as others have pointed out, is that your alarms are not "wakeup" alarms.  This means that if the device is asleep when the trigger time is reached, the alarm will not cause the device to wake up and process the alarm immediately.  Instead, it will be processed as soon as something else causes the device to become active, such as the user picking it up and pushing the power button to start using it.

The second issue is that you are using `setInexactRepeating()`.  As the name implies, these alarms are never going to be delivered at precisely predictable times.  As the documentation says, "In addition, while the overall period of the repeating alarm will be as requested, the time between any two successive firings of the alarm may vary."

This is often enough for most apps, and it is more efficient in terms of battery use.  However, if you truly need the alarm to be delivered at a specific time, you need to set the alarm time yourself instead of relying on periodic alarms.  In addition, as of API version 19, you should use the new `setExact()` APIs if you truly need precise delivery.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your observed inaccuracy may be caused by the subtle variation of flags for the alarms.

`AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME` and `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` utilize `elapsedRealtime()`, which is the number of milliseconds since the device last booted up, good for measuring elapsed time for timers and the like.

`AlarmManager.RTC` and `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` utilize `currentTimeMillis()`, which is the system clock:

> time in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC. This method shouldn't be used for measuring timeouts or other elapsed time measurements, as changing the system time can affect the results.

All four of the `AlarmManager` clock flags I've listed will include time spent in sleep, but only the `*_WAKEUP` flags will wake the device to sound the alarm; the default flags will wait until the device is otherwise awakened and then sound the alarm immediately.

Make sure you select the flag that matches your use-case, and ensure that the value of your delay {`Integer` at `sep[3]`?} is the amount of time to wait between alarms in milliseconds; as you have it, your `Integer` is being unboxed and cast to a long; it works, but unless there's a reason for it, I recommend switching to a primitive `long`; so a 15 minute delay would be:

```
int delay = 900000L // 15 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html